# How to make msvc preprocessor understand operator "and" and "or" along with "&&" and "||" in #if directives?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, preprocessor

I have code that has code like that

```c++
#if defined(A) and defined(b)
...
#endif
```

It fails with a lot of syntax errors which denotes that parsing failed
If I replace `and` with `&&` it compiles. I don't want to make changes in thirdparty library, is there a way to make it recognize those operators?

Comment: Side note: The (static?!) library you use along with that header seems to have been compiled with ...original... compiler settings. Maybe it is a good thing you stumbled across this problem. Who knows which other weird/unexpected settings they used...

Answer (score 3):

You can just

```
#include <iso646.h>
```

[That header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ciso646) defines [alternative tokens for the operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative). But it's really not a good way. Just use the normal C++ operators

[Demo on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:12,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:12),source:%27%23include+%3Ciso646.h%3E%0A%0A%23define+A%0A%23define+b%0A%0A%23if+defined(A)+and+defined(b)%0Avoid+f()%0A%7B%0A++++//+Function+is+defined%0A%7D%0A%23endif%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.976771196283394,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:68.63636363636364,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:31.36363636363636,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50.02322880371661,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: Would you please elaborate on why "_it's really not a good way_"? Those are built-in alternative tokens and can be used to improve readability (although that was not the primary motivation why they exist), without the need to include any headers in standard C++.

Comment: @heapunderrun it'll confuse most of the C and C++ programmers, hence most people will recommend against it. Few people know it so they'll have to lookup everytime to know that it's a logical or bitwise operator

Comment: Fair enough. I'm just against the idea that one needs to modify their standard-conformant C++ code (in this case even some third-party code) just because Microsoft's compiler does not follow the C++ standard strictly enough by default.

Answer (score 3):

Since in C++, `and` and `or` are built-it [alternative operator representations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative), the C++ version of `<iso646.h>` (and `<ciso646>`, which was removed in C++20) header file does not define anything. However, Microsoft's extensions to C++ conflict with those.

You can require strict language conformance by using the `/permissive-` switch. (Note that setting the C++ language standard level to C++20 using the `/std:c++20` switch will automatically enable strict conformance as well).

Another way is to use the `/Za` switch to [disable Microsoft's extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/za-ze-disable-language-extensions) to C++ language. (However, Microsoft does not recommend using `/Za` when code is compiled as C++.)